# Cyclic dependency using Knockout subscribe

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-subscribe

Is there any possible fix to the below code where I face cyclic dependency using Knockout.js subscribe.

```
this.observable1.subscribe(function(value){
self.observable2("someValue");
});

this.observable2.subscribe(function(value){
self.observable1("someValue");
});
```

Where "self" is an alias to "this" and observable1 linked to combo box, and observable2 linked to date picker.

Kindly suggest

Comment: Understanding why the combobox must affect the datepicker and vice versa may help in providing alternative solutions. Can you provide that reasoning?

Comment: Are you trying to keep the two of them in synch?

Comment: @TrueEddie, yes. I am trying to keep two of them in sync.

Comment: @Origineil, When I set combo box value to "time-period", datepicker has to populate date as per the time-period value (ex., current month) and when I edit Date field which is associated with date-picker, "time-period" has to change automatically to "custom".

Comment: You can use computed for this. Checkout this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Origineil said, you probably need to re-think your solution.

But if you really want to keep current solution, you could use a flag to break the cycle.

```
var isInnerUpdate = false;

this.observable1.subscribe(function(value){
  if (isInnerUpdate) {
    isInnerUpdate = false;
  } else {
    isInnerUpdate = true;
    self.observable2("someValue");
  }
});

this.observable2.subscribe(function(value){
    if (isInnerUpdate) {
    isInnerUpdate = false;
  } else {
    isInnerUpdate = true;
    self.observable1("someValue");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a global variable and logic as below and it worked fine for me,

```
var enableSubcribe = false; //global variable 
this.observable1.subscribe(function(value){ 
enableSubcribe = true; 
self.observable2("someValue");
enableSubcribe = false; 
}); 

this.observable2.subscribe(function(value){
 if(!enableSubcribe ){
self.observable1("someValue");
}
 });
```

Thanks to Huocp, your logic looks like works as well. Thanks all for your comments and answer.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, your enableSubscribe is not a global variable, it is a variable only visible in the function scope of your viewmodel constructor function.

Comment: sorry for that, the global variable has to be declared as  this.enableSubcribe = ko.observable(); in the constructor.